# How to extract all images from a "read-protected" PDF from Linux command line?

Tags: linux, pdf, imagemagick, mupdf, poppler

I'm trying to extract images from a PDF which is read protected.

With normal PDFs the [Poppler library](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) extracts images fine, and from read-protected PDFs it can also extract the text just fine. The images are a different story though. It either doesn't extract all images, or extracts all of them in vague grey or black colors.

On the following PDF ([original PDF here](http://www12.zippyshare.com/v/DgtCWgrd/file.html)) which has as you can see in the thumbnail below a lot of images:

[image]

I tried the `pdfimages` command from the [Poppler library](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/):

```
$ pdfimages -j ticket.pdf i
```

and the `pdftohtml` command from [mupdf](http://mupdf.com/):

```
$ pdftohtml -nodrm ticket.pdf
```

But both libs only extract one of the many images. That image is extracted correctly though. From other PDFs I get all images, but all of them are grey or black.

Since read-protection is supposedly only a flag in the PDF document, and not an actual scrambling or encryption of the source (in the end your computer can show the images without putting in a password) it should be possible somehow to extract the images individually. I can even create a thumbnail from the whole PDF using [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org/) (`convert ticket.pdf ticket.jpg`), so why not individual images?

Does anybody know how I can extract all images from read-protected PDFs? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'read protected' if you don't mean that its password protected. If its password protected then the contents most definitely are encrypted. You can't set permissions on a PDF file without supplying a password, so I'm somewhat puzzled. However, if you can extract text there's no reason you can't extract other content.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything what *looks* like an image also ***IS*** an image.

Take, for example, the red-blue-yellow-green logo on the top left corner with the black+white "ticket-service" text: It is a series of vector graphics (each of the red, blue, yellow and green patches is a separate object, as is the text).

The only "real" (raster) images are the ones listed by the following command:

```
$ pdfimages -list ticket.pdf 

 page   num  type   width height color comp bpc  enc interp  object ID x-ppi y-ppi size ratio
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1     0 image     642   462  index   1   8  image  no        38  0   151   151  107K  37%
    2     1 image     642   462  index   1   8  image  no        38  0   151   151  107K  37%
```

Both these (listed) images are represented by the same PDF object with the number/generation `38 0` (so it ***IS*** only 1 image embedded in the PDF).

Just because the page is colorful doesn't mean there are a lot of images embedded!

Also, there is no "read-protection" on the PDF (whatever that may mean for you), and there also is no (user or owner) password with companion encryption on that PDF, as is shown by the following command:

```
$ pdfinfo ticket.pdf

 Title:          TicketFast
 Author:         Ticketmaster
 Creator:        TCT 4.4.4
 Producer:       PDFlib+PDI 5.0.4 (C++/Linux)
 CreationDate:   Wed May  5 18:21:29 2010
 ModDate:        Thu Apr 30 16:02:21 2015
 Tagged:         no
 UserProperties: no
 Suspects:       no
 Form:           none
 JavaScript:     no
 Pages:          2
 Encrypted:      no
 Page size:      595.275 x 841.89 pts (A4)
 Page rot:       0
 File size:      364994 bytes
 Optimized:      no
 PDF version:    1.4
```

If there ***WAS*** password/encryption set on the PDF,  it would report so with the line `Encrypted:      yes`.

---

### Some comments about PDF protection

> *"[....] read-protection is supposedly only a flag in the PDF document [....]"*

First, there is no such thing as "read-protection". You probably mean "password protection".

Second, ***IF*** a PDF is password protected, it is also encrypted. There are two passwords:

1. The *owner* password which is required to make *changes* to the security/password/encryption status of the document.
2. The *user* password which is required to open and look at the document.

However, there are (quite common) cases when the user password is left "empty". All PDF readers know that, and they try that empty user "password" first. If it works, they de-crypt and open the PDF. PDFs with an empty user password may still be protected by limiting copy'n'paste, printing, modifying etc. To change that status you'd need to know the owner password...